# How to use the file names passed as input to shell script using loop statements?

Tags: shell, csh

> I am passing random number of files to a shell script and trying to
>   print it using a for loop. I tried something as below.

```
cat >> script.csh
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ ));
do
echo $i
done
```

> so if I do ./script.csh xyz.txt abc.txt pqr.txt
>
> I am expecting the output to be
>
> xyz.txt
>
> abc.txt
>
> pqr.txt
>
> But I am getting the output as
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that actually a csh script? Is `((...))` legal there?

Comment: @singe31 `$i` and `${i}` are identical.

Comment: Use `for arg; do echo "$arg"; done` to loop over all the arguments in `sh`/`bash`.

Comment: Hello  Etan Reisner...It is working....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through program arguments with this syntax:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    echo $i
done
```